# How to declare an initialized multidimensional array of a class using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, multidimensional-array

This does not work! How is it done?

```
class myClass
{
    public int x;
    public string y;

    public myClass()
    {
    }

    public myClass(int _x, string _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
}

myClass [,] myArray = new myClass[3,2] =
{
    {
        new myClass(1, "string11");
        new myClass(2, "string12");
    };
    {
        new myClass(1, "string21");
        new myClass(1, "string22");
    };
    {
        new myClass(1, "string31");
        new myClass(1, "string32");
    }
};
```

I am trying to create an initialized multidimensional array of a class and I cannot get the compiler to accept it. What am I doing wrong?

I changed the { to ( and changed the commas to semi-colons - still does not like the declareation myClass [,] myArray = new myClass[3,2] =

This seems to work:

```
myClass [,] myArray = new myClass[3,2] 
{
    {
        new myClass(1, "string11"),
        new myClass(2, "string12")
    },
    {
        new myClass(1, "string21"),
        new myClass(1, "string22")
    },
    {
        new myClass(1, "string31"),
        new myClass(1, "string32")
    }
};
```

Comment: "_What am I doing wrong?_" I am sure the compiler tells you what it thinks you did wrong. The first step in solving your problem should be reading the error messages the compiler gives (that includes reading the information about the code line that an error is about and which the error message mentions). Ignoring the information the compiler provides you about problems is usually not conducive to solving programming problems...

Comment: I bet that is not the actual error message  "I dont like the declareation myClass [,]..."

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-array

Answer (score 1):

In short

- You had the wrong syntax for the constructor `{` instead of `(`
- You had a `.` instead of an `,` in your array declaration.
- You had no commas between the array elements

Try this instead.

**Fixed**

```
private static void Main()
{

   var myArray = new myClass[3, 2]
                 {
                    {
                       new myClass(1, "string11"),
                       new myClass(2, "string12"),
                    },
                    {
                       new myClass(1, "string21"),
                       new myClass(1, "string22"),
                    },
                    {
                       new myClass(1, "string31"),
                       new myClass(1, "string32"),
                    }
                 };
}
```

Then it's probably time to take a look at the following documentation:

- [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)
- [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors)
- [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors and the compiler still will not accept it. I edited the sample to reflect the changes